# how to get the value of id attribute of current editable selection of ckEeditor inline mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

i am trying to implement ckeditor's inline editing for first time,i have gone through documentations and solutions but i haven't found any solution for my issue.

the content of the div tag that i am modifying does not have a  unique id ,actually its generated at run time like this

```
<%
    for(Section subSection:subSections) {
%>
    <div class="editable" id="contact<%=subSection.getSectionId()%>" contenteditable="true">
             <content goes here that also comes from db>
    </div> 
<%}%>
```

i am able to show the current selected content using on click of save button like this

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] = {
    init: function (editor) {
        var command = editor.addCommand('save',
        {
            modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
            exec: function (editor) { // Add here custom function for the save button

                console.log(editor.getData());

            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton('Save', { label: 'Save', command: 'save' });
    }
}
```

but i need the value of Id attribute also of currently selected div   which i am not sure how to get.
i was able to do this in tinymce with `var div_id = tinymce.activeEditor.id;`if that helps in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `editor.element.getId()`. Use it in your command's exec method. Read more about [`CKEDITOR.editor#element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-element).

Comment: In inline mode `editor.container` == `editor.element`. But in other modes `editor.container` is the topmost UI container while `editor.element` refers to textarea.

Comment: ok got your point and it saved me some more work as this was also something that i needed so thanks a lot :)